# SQL: IF NULL THEN '-' ,ELSE condition

Tags: sql

mo_orders table:

```
mo_name   admin_id
abcd        2
xyz        NULL
```

login_details table:

```
id     username
1       Mark
2       John
3       Bob
```

I wrote a SQL Statement similar like this (the original one looks different but I want to give an easy example here):

```
select ld.username 
from mo_orders mo inner join login_details ld on mo.admin_id=ld.id;
```

This Statement does not have any syntax errors but how to write a statement when `admin_id` is `NULL` then print `'-'` else `mo.admin_id=ld.id` ?

Comment: What exactly is the output you want (based on your sample data). Please **[edit]** your question and add that (the same way you included the sample data)

Comment: Already try ISNULL() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `left join` with `coalesce()`:

```
select mo.*, coalesce(ld.username, '-') as username
from mo_orders mo left join
     login_details ld 
     on mo.admin_id = ld.id;
```